# Why can I not register a custom JSON.Net implementation in Nancy?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nancy

I have the following installed:

```
  <package id="Nancy" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Nancy.Owin" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net4" />
```

And also:

```
public sealed class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var options = new NancyOptions();
        app.UseNancy(options);
    }
}

public sealed class CustomJsonNetSerializer : JsonSerializer
{
    public CustomJsonNetSerializer()
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }
}
```

Then in my `Bootstrapper`:

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

    container.Register<JsonSerializer, CustomJsonNetSerializer>();
}
```

And finally in the route:

```
public sealed class ApiBase : NancyModule
{
    public ApiBase() : base("api/")
    {
        Get["user/"] = o => Response.AsJson(new { Context.CurrentUser, Time = DateTime.UtcNow});
    }
}
```

However when running this app, the `CustomJsonNetSerializer` is never instantiated, it looks like Nancy is using a different implementation possibly the `ISerializer`.

Please note I want to know why this solution is failing as I am following the official [doc](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet) rather than doing other implementation i.e implementing an `ISerializer`.

Any idea?

**[Update]**
I could not figure out what was wrong so I ended up with:

```
public sealed class CustomJsonNetSerializer : JsonSerializer, ISerializer
{
    public CustomJsonNetSerializer()
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
        Formatting = Formatting.None;
    }

    public bool CanSerialize(string contentType)
    {
        return contentType.Equals("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public void Serialize<TModel>(string contentType, TModel model, Stream outputStream)
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
        using(var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
        {
            Serialize(jsonWriter, model);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Extensions { get { yield return "json"; } }
}
```

And:

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

    container.Register<ISerializer, CustomJsonNetSerializer>();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352833/how-to-get-a-response-from-the-nancy-negotiator refer this, you can use Negotiaer return type or return with negotiate ()

Comment: Addendum: Also see related SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873171

Comment: The updated code above worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that your custom serializer is not used?

I can see that breakpoint set to the `CustomJsonNetSerializer` is hit.

The response contains correctly formatted JSON file:

```
{
  "currentUser": null,
  "time": "2015-11-29T15:01:55.4669533Z"
}
```

If I change the `DateFormatHandling` 
to

```
DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
```

the change will be reflected as expected:

```
{
  "currentUser": null,
  "time": "\/Date(1448809002853)\/"
}
```

## Could you make sure that your application is configured correctly:

You have `Startup` class in the root namespace of your application (is it OWIN?). Annotate `Startup` class with OwinStartup annotation. Something like:

`[assembly:OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication3.Startup))]`

```
public class Startup
{
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.UseNancy();
            }
}
```

You have only one `Bootstrapper`

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
        {
            base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

            container.Register<JsonSerializer, CustomJsonNetSerializer>();
        }
    }
```

Verify all the package's versions:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Nancy" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Nancy.Owin" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net4" />
</packages>
```

Comment: In my case it's not being hit regardless the changes I make to the CustomSerializer I get the same output. Which version of `.Net` did you build against? 4.5 or 4?

Comment: I used 4.5 for the test

Comment: Updated the question with the `Startup`, I suspect this is due to 4 vs 4.5

Comment: hm, let me try wit .NET 4

Comment: and it works exactly the same way regardless the .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem, basically it seems that the CustomSerializer is registered BUT the response.AsJson it is not using it. I add the registered serializer on the contructor in the module and if I manually Serialize the object and send a AsText response it will work. Can it be that the problem is that method AsJson is not using the custom serializer?

So, in the bootstrap I'm do as you

```
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
        container.Register<System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer>(CustomJsonSerializer);
    }
```

But then in the module

```
public class SimpleModule : Nancy.NancyModule
{
        Get["/State/"] = parameters =>
        {
            string Json = TheSerializer.Serialize(myobject);
            return Response.AsText(Json);
            // return Response.AsJson(myobject);
        };        
}
```

Switching that comments on the response will end up in 2 different JSON responses. A wrong one when using AsJson method.